# applying text-indent for multi-line text. JQuery

Tags: jquery, text-indent

Text-indent for a multiline text doesn't seem to be working. As shown in the below picture text-indent dosen't seem to apply for the word **`years:`******(Circled in red**)**.

Please advice.

```
 var indent =
        {
            'margin': '0px',
            'padding': '0px',
            'text-indent': '30px'
        };

$('.HideShow td:nth-child(2)').css(indent);
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

BB

Comment: `text-indent` affects only the first line of the text block.

Comment: is there a tweak to apply it to multi line.

Comment: In your case you should use `padding` instead of `text-indent`

Comment: Thank you. Padding is affecting(increasing) the Width of the element. How can avoid that happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **`'padding-left':'30px'`** instead of  **`'text-indent': '30px'`** fixes the issue.